# Identical CSS but different result?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am editing `estatesalesbyyou.com` and on the front page slider, for some reason some slides have big gaps around the text, and other ones its more complete. 

I am using the `Wordpress` page builder (I'd rather do just bare bones coding but my boss is making me) and I have input identical markup for all of the slides, yet they look different.

> One difference I did put in, was a line height of 80% for the slides
>   where the text appeared to be double spaced, instead of the spacing
>   found on the first slider.

Does anyone know why the same markup is causing such different results?  Or, how I can achieve uniformity with all of the slides labels being styled the same way?

The code for slides where I changed the line-height to try to make them match up better:

```
<div class="et_pb_slide_content">
<div style="background: #000000; height: 20px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; width: 100%;">
<h3>COMMERCIAL LIQUIDATIONS, DOWNSIZING/MOVING SALES AND MORE</h3>
</div>
<div style="background: #000000; text-align:center;width:98%;">
<p style="margin:10px;text-align: center;line-height:90%;">The Estate Sales business allows for many types of sales opportunities. We’ll show you the many possibilities available to you when you’re an estate sale business owner. <a href="http://estatesalesbyyou.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/clear-fill.png"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-641" src="http://estatesalesbyyou.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/clear-fill.png" alt="clear-fill" width="100" height="40"></a></p>
</div>
</div>
```

The code for slides where I didn't modify the line-height:

```
<div class="et_pb_slide_content">
<div style="background: #000000; height: 20px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; width: 100%;">
<h3>ESTATE SALES BY YOU PROVIDES A TURNKEY BUSINESS FOR YOUR AREA</h3>
</div>
<p><!--

<div style="background: #000000; opacity: 0.8; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
--></p>
<div style="background: #000000; text-align:center;width:98%;">
<p style="margin:10px;text-align: center;">From your website to your marketing materials and strategies, Estate Sales By You provides the foundation you need to start your own business.</p>
<p><span style="color: #000000;">&nbsp;.<a href="http://estatesalesbyyou.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/clear-fill.png"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-641" src="http://estatesalesbyyou.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/clear-fill.png" alt="clear-fill" width="100" height="40"></a></span></p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you should provide some code of your css and html.

Comment: The differences exist because the content of the `<div>`s are different. For some slides, there is two `<p>`'s as content, for others there is one `<p>` and one `<a>` with an invisible image. The latter ones expand the height of the entire `<div>`, causing the `<p>` the spread its text vertically as well.